# Unable to access Notebooks on Azure ML Studio

Tags: azure, ml-studio

On the Azure ML Studio, when I try to create a new notebook by clicking on R blank workbook, I get an error saying, "Access Denied. You do not have access to the specified notebook.
If someone shared this link with you please ask them to share the link to their library instead of sharing the link to their running notebook server.

Otherwise check if you are still signed in and please login again if you've been signed out."
I am definitely signed in. What else could be the issue?[image: Screenshot of the error message attached]

Comment: This same issue is still ongoing. Two tickets have been raised on the Github page for Azure Notebooks but with no result yet.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.